# One battery backup, two garage doors

Tags: battery-charging, backup

I have made a very simple battery backup for my garage door: 2 x 12 V batteries in series connected to the battery terminals of my opener.

This charges the battery and switches to backup on power failure.

My question is: before I build a second backup for my other door, can I simply wire both doors into this one backup?  I am concerned with having two door openers charging the batteries at the same time.

I was considering having an DPDT switch so the one backup can open both doors but I have to manually switch between them.

But if there are no issues wiring them together it would be best option.

Comment: It all depends on how intelligent the charging circuits are. To know that requires knowing the circuitry at the very least so, please supply a schematic circuit diagram. If you can't then how can you get an answer?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I am a very novice DIYer. It is a Liftmaster LM 80evs  and sorry I cannot find out anything about how the device charges the backup battery. I have tested and it is not putting 24v from the device to charge the batteries. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Block both positive lines from charging the battery, use a diode, and put a tricycle charger on the battery separately.

That's what I would do.